# Vertically resize DIV elements within parent height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

<sup>**Demoralizes to see downvotes**, I really did my best (I believe) to explain my issue and keep it short and simple. If you find hard to understand the question I'm willing to follow-up with any *improvement* suggestions :,(</sup>

I'm trying to create a **100% height vertical sidebar** that has N number of **resizable children** elements - something like Facebook sidebar (chat...) or Photoshop's sidebar

[image]

where the children do not exceed the parent height and resizing one element the other should resize accordingly, so practically the added children heights should always match the (100%) parent height.

I tried to resize table rows but again without success...
This what I have so far using **CSS3 flex** (seemed like a good idea) :(

```js
$("#panel>div").resizable({
  handles:'s'     /* try using "n" to see what happens... */
});
```

```css
*{margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}
html, body{height:100%;}
[class^=ui-resizable]{height:2px;background:#08f;cursor:row-resize;}

#panel{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column ;
  height:100%;
  width:200px;
}
#panel>div{
  flex: 1;
  background:#aaa;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="panel">
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
  <div id="c">c</div>
</div>
```

You can clearly see in the above demo that due the use of `flex` jQuery is unable to resize the elements....

How would you approach to this problem (without plugins)? **thanks**

Comment: Always seek a solution that involves less code. Easier said than done of course, but I see a solution that may only require properly configured flexbox layout. Standby for an answer, sir. Btw, I don't see anything wrong with your question, I suspect there are some individuals that randomly deface questions by down voting. Hopefully my up vote will help your question bubble to the top. :)

Comment: @zer00ne you're a real gentleman! **I don't insist on using flexbox** I'm just interested to see different ideas and approaches - learn something new... Thank you!

Comment: Upon further inspection, I see you want be able to manually re-size the flex children. This'll require extra time, but like the idea.

Comment: @zer00ne yes, I think it's an interesting problem after all. So basically the resizable elements should have scrollbars if the content exceeds the height. Their cumulative heights should always match the container height (like i.e: `a+b+c=always 100%`) So similar to Facebook's right sidebar (on Desktop) and like Photoshop's layers sidebar. I've done an extensive research on SO finding only plugins suggestions (that does no teach much)

Comment: I don't have the time to write out a full answer now, but if there's none by tomorrow i will. I just figured i could aim you in 'a' right direction by saying you can  use the resize event handlers to simultaniously resize the previous div (or if it doesn't exist, the next div) while you resize the first. The 'ui object' keeps track of the original size as well as the current, so all you need to do is keep track of the neighbours starting size, and update it's current size based on the current size of the object you're resizing. Hope that helps, if it doesn't, i'll write it out tomorrow.

Comment: @DrunkWolf (thanks) so actually there's no way to hack into CSS using flex or resize properties? (I mean without JS?)

Comment: Well the thing is, as far as i know, and i'll be quite glad if someone proves me wrong, since that means i've learnt something new, but the other thing you can do; which is temporarily disabling the flex property on the box you're resizing, makes it so the others resize at the same time, which gives a very strange user experience. You could temporarily disable the flex property on the box you use, and all other boxes except a neighbour, but that's harder to implement then my suggestion. The solution i propose is quite simple to implement, and gives a very predictable user case.

Comment: @DrunkWolf interesting thoughts! Tanks for sharing. I'll take into account and try. I'll let you know if I get anything interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out i had some time after all :) [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0cep2g9/7/)

So key code in this is that when you start resizing you select a neighbour you also want to resize as such:

```
if ($(this).next('.resiz').length>0){
    other= $(this).next('.resiz');
 }else{
    other = $(this).prev('.resiz');
 }
 startingHeight= other.height();
```

And store it's height. Then when we resize, we also resize the other one as such

```
 resize:function(e,ui){
     var dh = ui.size.height-ui.originalSize.height;
     if (dh>startingHeight){// can't resize the box more then it's neighbour
         dh =  startingHeight;
         ui.size.height = ui.originalSize.height+dh;
     }
     other.height(startingHeight-dh);
 }
```

Hope that works for you

Comment: Though there's still a minor issue, enlarge the height of the second DIV... the parent increases height... any quicky?

Comment: I didn't have that issue upon testing, so that snuck in with your changes I think. Don't have the time now to look at it, hope you work it out :)

Comment: There's also in your demo, no worries. You helped already a lot. I think some `Math.min` will get that sorted. Thx again

Comment: Added a quick fix on the resizing past neighbours boundary issue

Comment: Thanks so much! I've edited your example to also include i.e: 50px min size! http://jsfiddle.net/y0cep2g9/9/ (Seems also that we never needed `.prev()`...) :D

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 flexboxes aren't very well supported and might not be very well suited to this task. Set resize: vertical on the elements and use a javascript listener to resize all of your divs when one is resized. I don't know how specifically you want to implement resizing and I don't have the patience to write something that involved from scratch for no pay, but what I can offer you is a little javascript that might help you add event listeners to all of the elements of a class.

```
function resizeboxes() {
    //resize your boxes here.
}

sections = document.querySelectorAll(".resizable-boxes");
for(i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
    sections[i].addEventListener("resize", resizeboxes);
}
```

Comment: I'm not married to `flex` just trying to figure if there's maybe some (i.e: CSS's) `resize:vertical;` (so preferably CSS) or some other nice easy trick (JS/jQuery) to get the job done.

Comment: There is, in fact, a css property called resize which can be set to vertical. Unfortunately I don't believe there is a pure CSS way to do what you want without using flexbox. Why don't you go ahead and try using "resize: vertical" in your #panel>div rule and see what that does?

Comment: unfortunately `resize` opens another Pandora's box... Thanks for your great support. 1'd.