# Vertical dragBar for resizing two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted a vertical dragBar for resizing two divs. I have created an example for the same but I am facing an issue. 
Actual : As and when I resize the the upper div and move the slider down, the area of parent div increases and hence a scroll bar is given. 
Expected: When Resizing, if the slider is moved down, it should only show the data contained in the upper div and when slider is moved up, it should show the content of lower div and should not increase the over all length of the parent div.

```js
var handler = document.querySelector('.handler');
var wrapper = handler.closest('.wrapper');
var boxA = wrapper.querySelector('.box1');
var boxB = wrapper.querySelector('.box2');
var isHandlerDragging = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  // If mousedown event is fired from .handler, toggle flag to true
  if (e.target === handler) {
    isHandlerDragging = true;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  // Don't do anything if dragging flag is false
  if (!isHandlerDragging) {
    return false;
  }

  // Get offset
  var containerOffsetTop= wrapper.offsetTop;
  var containerOffsetBottom= wrapper.offsetBottom;


  // Get x-coordinate of pointer relative to container
  var pointerRelativeXpos = e.clientY - containerOffsetTop;
  var pointerRelativeXpos2 = e.clientY - e.offsetTop + e.offsetHeight;
  
 
  var boxAminWidth = 30;

  
  boxA.style.height = (Math.max(boxAminWidth, pointerRelativeXpos - 2)) + 'px';
  boxA.style.flexGrow = 0;
   boxB.style.height = (Math.max(boxAminWidth, pointerRelativeXpos2 - 8)) + 'px';
  boxB.style.flexGrow = 0;
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  // Turn off dragging flag when user mouse is up
  isHandlerDragging = false;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  /* Use flexbox */
  
}

.box1, .box2 {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin-top:2%;
  
  /* Use box-sizing so that element's outerwidth will match width property */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* Allow box to grow and shrink, and ensure they are all equally sized */
 
}

.handler {
  width: 20px;
  height:7px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: ns-resize;
}

.handler::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">A</div>
  <div class="handler"></div>
  <div class="box2">B</div>
</div>
```

Hope I was clear in explaining the issue I am facing in my project. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically resize DIV elements within parent height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169284/vertically-resize-div-elements-within-parent-height)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your on the right track.  You just need to make the wrapper a flexbox with the flex direction column and assign it a height.  Also box 2 needs to have a flex of 1 so it can grow and shrink as needed.  Finally I needed to remove the code that set the flex grow to 0 in the JavaScript.  Here is the result.

```js
var handler = document.querySelector('.handler');
    var wrapper = handler.closest('.wrapper');
    var boxA = wrapper.querySelector('.box1');
    var boxB = wrapper.querySelector('.box2');
    var isHandlerDragging = false;

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        // If mousedown event is fired from .handler, toggle flag to true
        if (e.target === handler) {
            isHandlerDragging = true;
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        // Don't do anything if dragging flag is false
        if (!isHandlerDragging) {
            return false;
        }

        e.preventDefault();

        // Get offset
        var containerOffsetTop= wrapper.offsetTop;
        var containerOffsetBottom= wrapper.offsetBottom;


        // Get x-coordinate of pointer relative to container
        var pointerRelativeXpos = e.clientY - containerOffsetTop;
        var pointerRelativeXpos2 = e.clientY - e.offsetTop + e.offsetHeight;


        var boxAminWidth = 30;


        boxA.style.height = (Math.max(boxAminWidth, pointerRelativeXpos - 2)) + 'px';
        boxB.style.height = (Math.max(boxAminWidth, pointerRelativeXpos2 - 8)) + 'px';
    });
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
        // Turn off dragging flag when user mouse is up
        isHandlerDragging = false;
    });
```

```css
body {
            margin: 40px;
        }

        .wrapper {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #444;
            /* Use flexbox */
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 200px;
        }

        .box1, .box2 {
            background-color: #444;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 150%;
            margin-top:2%;

            /* Use box-sizing so that element's outerwidth will match width property */
            box-sizing: border-box;

            /* Allow box to grow and shrink, and ensure they are all equally sized */

        }


        .box2 {
            flex: 1;
        }

        .handler {
            width: 20px;
            height:7px;
            padding: 0;
            cursor: ns-resize;
        }

        .handler::before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100%;
            background: red;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box1">A</div>
    <div class="handler"></div>
    <div class="box2">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot :) You saved my day :) This solved my above raised issue. But now after this change I am facing a new issue. The slider handle is scroll-able even in mouse-up state. Not able to guess what caused this issue

Comment: It seems to happen when you attempt to drag something at the same time as resizing the divs.  For example when you accidentally select the next at the same time.  I was able to prevent this by adding e.preventDefault() to your mousemove event.  I've edited my answer :)

Comment: Hey I tried the same in my jsFiddle code. It worked perfectly. Thanx a lot :). But when I tried the same code in my own project, the problem raises again. I am posting my project's jsfiddle example. Can you please point out what is going wrong in this? As I have used the same code and css property as above, but when i double-click on the handle, the handle goes up, and resizing is also not perfect when the handled is moved at bottom end. JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kn507gtw/